# What does *:: (asterisk double colon) do in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, syntax, scope, splat

I was poking through the Rails code today and stumbled upon [this snippet](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/807e176aba7804cad8d630d04f3b771011be4fe6/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/column.rb#L262):

```
new_date(*::Date._parse(string, false).values_at(:year, :mon, :mday))
```

What does the asterisk-double-colon (or splat-double-colon if you will) in `*::Date` do?

Presumably it has something to do with the scope of a particularly-namespaced `Date` class... but it's necessary enough for the author to include it rather than just use the standard `Date` class.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was reading the code wrong; it's not a "*::" operator at all.

Here's what's happening:

- Find the `Date` class in the global scope (`::Date`)
- call `_parse()` to get a hash of values
- call `values_at` to turn the hash into an array
- use the asterisk operator in its typical function of turning an array into multiple arguments for a method call
- call `new_date()`, passing the array elements in for its `year`, `mon`, and `mday` arguments.

The lack of space between the `*` and `::` operators made it confusing. :-\

Comment: The first bullet point should say "in the **global** scope". The current scope would be without the `::`.

Comment: And that's an excellent example why sometimes, using local variables is a good idea.